# Manipular un puntero char dentro de una funcion y devolver su ultimo valor modificado (C)

Tags: c, string, funciones, punteros

Bueno lo que pasa es lo siguiente, no puedo lograr que la funcion `validaLinea` retorne una cadena con una palabra menos que es fija y siempre esta al principio del `char`, lo que hago es dar vuelta el string, copiar todo lo que tengo que sacar, y volver a darlo vuelta, dentro de la función esto funciona, pero al usar el return y volver al `main` cuando lo imprimo no es el mismo valor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct estructura {         
    char linea[256];
    int cant;
};

void cargaLinea(char *, int *);     
char validaLinea(char *, int);         

int main() {
    int i;
    struct estructura directorios[3], aux;
    int cantlinea;  
    char linea[256], *lineab[256], lineac;

    lineab[256] = &linea[256];

    cargaLinea(&linea[256], &cantlinea);
    cantlinea = cantlinea - 5;

    linea[256] = validaLinea(lineab[256], cantlinea);  

    printf("La cadena despues de validar: %s \n", &linea[256]); 
}

void cargaLinea(char *l, int *cl) {  
    int cont, i;

    printf("Ingrese directorio a crear: ");
    gets(l);

    for (i=0; l[i] != '\0'; i++)
        cont = cont + 1;
    *cl = cont;
}


char validaLinea(char *l, int cl) { //ERROR
    int op;
    char *aux, *aux2, *aux3;

    op = strncmp(l, "mkdir", 5);    

    if (op == 0) {
        printf("Sintaxis correcta, creando directorio...\n");

        aux = strrev(l);
        printf("%s \n", aux);

        aux2 = strncpy(aux2, aux, cl);
        printf("%s \n", aux2);

        aux3 = strrev(aux2);
        printf("%s \n", aux3);

        return (*aux3);
    } else {
        printf("Sintaxis incorrecta \n");
    };      
}
```

Comment: Al correrlo ingresar la cadena mkdir +(espacio) +(lo que deberia salir de la funcion sin el mkdir)

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código no entiendo bien lo que estás haciendo. En la función main defines linea como array de 256 caracteres y también defines un array de 256 punteros a chars en lineab. La siguiente linea no tiene sentido:

```
lineab[256] = &linea[256];
```

Estás guardando en lineab, en la posición 256, que no tiene reservada porque has reservado de la 0 a la 255, la dirección de memoria del elemento 256 de linea, que tampoco es tuya porque solo puedes referenciar de la 0 a la 255. La posición 256 está fuera de tu array y si no te da excepción poco te falta.

En la llamada `cargaLinea(&linea[256], &cantlinea);` estás pasando como primer parámetro la dirección de memoria del elemento 256 de linea y no la linea entera, que como te dije antes, no es de tu array (solo de la posición 0 a la 255 al haber reservado 256 caracteres).

Si defines `char linea[256]`, podrás referirte luego a la variable usando el nombre de la misma, osea `linea` y no `linea[256]`. Y si lo que querías con lineab era un puntero a una cadena, si haces algo como:

char linea[256], *lineab;
lineab = linea;

lineab y linea apuntarán a la misma dirección de memoria. Si pasas cualquiera de las dos variables a una función que cambia el contenido de los caracteres, al salir de la función las dos variables seguirán apuntando a la misma dirección de memoria que tiene el mismo contenido.

No puedo ayudarte más porque no es problema de lo que hace la función validaLinea, sino de todo el programa que tampoco entiendo del todo. Te aconsejo que revises documentación de uso y definición de arrays y punteros en C. Un saludo.